# Windows PC laptop with built-in mac-like keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboards

I find that on my MacBook, I am much less likely to hit wrong keys than on any Windows PC I have ever used. The number pad and especially num lock are crimes against humanity, comparable to Francisco Solano López; lack of them has to help. This in turn means that the MacBook has fewer keys, and the space between them is greater. That has to help, too. Beyond that, I'm not sure what the causes are. Any suggestions, or, for that matter, insight? The keyboard has to be built into the computer, not an add-on.

EDIT: I'm a developer. I would expect to spend 1-2K. 16GB RAM is a very good thing. I would hope to use it heavily for 4 years or so. I would want to be able to open up (say) two VS solutions, SSMS, Notepad, SourceTree, Task Manager, Command prompt and two browsers without seriuosly degrading performance. A big screen is a very good thing.

Comment: Do you have any other requirements (price, performance, etc.) for the PC?

Comment: You can use a wireless Mac keyboard with a Windows computer

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking at different laptops and cannot see one with a Mac keyboard layout.

You could buy a Macbook [(I found one which has your specs here)](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NEW-Apple-Macbook-Pro-2-5GHz-2-5-GHz-15-4-MJLT2-i7-16GB-RAM-512GB-RETINA-2015-/381476421415?hash=item58d1c43f27:g:3BUAAOxygj5Sd8Lf)
and install Windows OS on it.

You can find a tutorial on installing Windows on Mac [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-on-MacBook-Pro-with-Retina-Displ/?ALLSTEPS)

Hope that helps